# File Object is not binding into controller scope variable, If ng-controller is not specified in HTML template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> I'm trying to upload a file using angularjs file-model directive. In my
>   project I have used $stateProvider for routing with attached
>   controller in it. I have routed into file upload template with
>   corresponding controller. But, when I tried to upload the file, file
>   is selected properly without error. But, when I console out that
>   particular selected object in its respective controller scope it is
>   showing undefined!!!. How to make that file object accessible through
>   out once that file has been selected in controller scope.

**Here, in below image I have mentioned my routing structure.**

[image]

As I mentioned in the image above, I have defined the main state called **library** and its corresponding controller in it. And below to that main state are called sub-states as we routed into that sub-state as we say for now **library.first** The scope goes into main state controller that is **libraryDeductionCtrl** and the template we'll get in view is **Payroll_InputActivity_MakerLibraryPage.html**.

**Structure of Payroll_InputActivity_MakerLibraryPage.html is given below.**

```
<section class="col-xs-12 no_pad  commonSections">
<div class="col-xs-12 no_pad FirstLibraryPage" ng-if="librarySkipStatus.skipFlag =='y' ? true : false">

    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>ALERT!</strong> {{librarySkipStatus.skipFlagMsg}}
    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 no_pad FirstLibraryPage" ng-if="librarySkipStatus.skipFlag =='y' ? false : true">

    <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad navbar_heading">
        <div class="pull-left backbtn_text">
            <h2 class="pull-left link_cls">Payroll has started, functional
                upload is pending with you</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 no_pad padding30">
        <div class="col-xs-12 no_pad borderAll padd15">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 no_pad margTop20">
                <label class="col-xs-12 no_pad" for="uplaod1">Upload</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 no_pad posRel">
                    <input type="text" class="browseInput1 input2 pull-left" id="uplaod1">
                    <input type="file" file-model="xlsLibrary" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" class="uploadFile1" data-role="none"> // Here i passing the xlsx file with using xlsLibrary scope variable
                    <button type="text " class="button_1 pull-left transform" aria-hidden="true">Browse</button>
                    <button type="text" class="button_2 pull-left transform" ng-click="uploadLibraryDeduction(xlsLibrary)">Upload</button>
                    <button class="icon-file_download btnDownload" ng-click="downloadTemplates()" role="button" aria-label="download" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download Template" style="padding:5px;margin-right: 10px">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> You might have seen in above HTML template there's no need to mention ng-controller explicitly. Because, as I mentioned it in routing config which is shown in above image. So, could anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.